# Strange and hard to debug errors when used in DI environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, autofac

Im currently using EF6 in a IOC setup using Autofac.
In my service i inject my DbContext like this:

```
    private readonly CommerceContext _dbContext;

    public UserTokenService(CommerceContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
```

When i update my token, a couple of different SQL errors occur randomly.

My ApiController:

```
private readonly IUserTokenService _tokenService;

public UsersApiController(IUserTokenService tokenService)
{
    this._tokenService = tokenService;
}

[RequireHttps]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/users/validatetoken")]
public IHttpActionResult ValidateToken(Guid tokenId)
{
    var falseObj = new
    {
        IsValid = false,
        Email = string.Empty
    };

    var token = _tokenService.Get(tokenId);
    if (token == null) return Ok(falseObj);
    if (token.IsExpired) return Ok(falseObj);

    var user = _userService.Find(token.UserId);
    if (user == null) return Ok(falseObj);

    _tokenService.Update(token);
}
```

My TokenService get method:

```
    public UserToken Get(Guid token)
    {
        return _dbContext.UserTokens.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Token == token);
    }
```

My TokenService update method:

```
    public void Update(UserToken token)
    {
        token.ExpiresAt = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

_dbContext contains all my different DbSets, and is registered like this:

```
  var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
  builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
  builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
  builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
  builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());

  builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(CommerceContext).Assembly)
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Context"))
    .InstancePerRequest();

  builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerRequest();

  var container = builder.Build();
  DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

Every call to the method is web api from a different domain.
I'm pretty much stuck.
I haven't experienced the error myself, but i can see it in my server log.
The only possibility i can think of, is that there is too many connections open at once, which would be really bad since the site currently don't have a lot of users.
Should i maybe register my DbContext differently, have more than one, or something completely different.

**Different errors:**

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting.
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosedConnecting.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at #.UserTokenService.Update(UserToken token) in E:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\38cf8b2b27f5e099\src\#\UserTokenService.cs:line 79

System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: SqlConnection does not support parallel transactions.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginSqlTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName, Boolean shouldReconnect)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.BeginTransaction(DbConnection connection, BeginTransactionInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginTransaction()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at #.UserTokenService.Update(UserToken token) in E:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\38cf8b2b27f5e099\src\#\UserTokenService.cs:line 79
```

Comment: _SqlConnection does not support parallel transactions_... I'm guessing you're starting 2 transactions on the same `DbContext`. Please show us how you register `UserTokenService`, how it's injected in the `ApiController` and how the Api controller are registered with Autofac. And also the code that begins the transaction.

Comment: It's a bit surprising that you store expiration of a user token. Seemingly you're taking care of all authentication yourself, while it would be better to use something like IdentityServer. It seems that authentication and business logic are running in parallel now during one request.

Comment: Ignore the _and also the code that begins the transaction_ of my first comment as I see the call-stack comes from `dbContext.SaveChanges()`.

Comment: *Should i maybe register my DbContext differently* - Can't say. Although I suspect this is the problem, you are not showing how you registered it. For that matter, you are not showing how the DI container is setup. If you really are using asp.net (not asp.net-mvc) as your tags would indicate, then this could be a very complicated DI setup. Please show the relevant parts of the DI configuration that affect lifetime of the `DbContext` in your question.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit When DbContext is created once per request, how can it run in parallel? Unless it uses the same SqlConnection behind the scenes. It's not like i'm calling any async methods in my method.

Comment: If you only create 1 `UserTokenService` for the entire application f.e., you'll be reusing that one `DbContext` for the entire lifetime of your application (not that this is the case here, but it's a common IoC mistake)

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit all my services is instance per request:

      builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .InstancePerRequest();

So that shouldn't be the problem. And what really spins my head, is why it's showing different sql errors. Hmm.

Comment: [Per-Controller-Type Service Limitations](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#per-controller-type-service-limitations) may have the answer (not sure).

Comment: @CyrilDurand i wish, but i'm not using per controller type service configuration.

Comment: It looks like the `DbContext` is shared but can't understand why. Do you use `async` somewhere? How often this problem happens ? Do you have a SQL Profiler trace?

Answer (score 2):

I found that my problem was caused by an WebApi ActionFilter attribute i made to validate the authentication token.

Inside this attributes OnActionExecuting i stored my UserTokenService in a private variable, getting the service from DependencyResolver.

This turned out to be a really bad solution because WebApi ActionFilter attributes is being cached, so basically my service was being shared by every api request by which the attribute was being used.

The solution was to use the scope provided by the HttpRequestMessage inside OnActionExecuting() like this:

```
    var scope = actionContext.Request.GetDependencyScope();
    var tokenService = scope.GetService(typeof(IUserTokenService)) as IUserTokenService;
```

An even better solution would be to use AutoFacs implementation of an ActionFilterAttribute described here:

http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#provide-filters-via-dependency-injection

This gives the opportunity to controller inject your ActionFilter.
But in my case its a better option to require the service from the scope.